# Invalid Namespace when automating Get-WMIObject

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to automate the retrieval of OS architecture and when I do I get an Invalid Namespace error.

```
    foreach($i in $hosts){

         $ip = $i.name
         Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ip Win32_OperatingSystem

    }
```

If I take Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ip Win32_OperatingSystem and replace $ip with a legit IP it works perfectly. I even added Write-Host to the front of Get-WMIObject so it would display the entire command that would run. I ran the output from Write-Host and the command completes successfully.

Error:
Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace 
At line:4 char:18
+     Get-WmiObject <<<<  -ComputerName $ip Win32_OperatingSystem
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

The $hosts variable is a PSCustomObject with two noteProperty fields. The first is name and the second is user. The name field holds an IP address of the system.

Comment: What's the content of $hosts, and where is it coming from?

Comment: The $hosts file is a PSCustomObject with two noteProperty fields. The first is name and the second is user. The name field holds an IP address of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were trailing whitespaces after the IPs. I used .trim() and now everything works just fine.